# Raster extract function problem

Tags: raster, r, extract

I used to run the extract function from raster package without any problem. However, recently I receive an error message and it does not work for me. When I run the extract function to extract stacked rasters along with my data points I receive the following error.

```
EHFextract <- extract(Stack_Rasters, Points_data, sp = 1, method = "simple")


  Error in .doExtract(x, i, ..., drop = drop) : 
  unused arguments (sp = TRUE, method = "simple")
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is, check your arguments. If it was a namespace conflict then the error would indicate an incorrect object class.

Comment: Show us what `summary(Stack_Rasters)` and `summary(Points_data)` produce - otherwise we're guessing.

Answer (score 5):

Could be a conflict between two packages with a function with the same name. To avoid this problem use:

```
EHFextract <- raster::extract(Stack_Rasters, Points_data, sp = 1, method = "simple")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers: I added raster:: to the extract function and it works perfect now.

Comment: @BabakK you are welcome. You can accept the answer if you want